# Реализация многопоточности в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, классы

У меня есть класс счётчик, функция work должна запускать его роботу(значение каждую секунду меняется от мин до макс, когда доходит до макс, то сбрасывается в мин), а функция check_current показывает текущее значение когда захочет пользователь. Мне нужно, чтобы одновременно работали обе функции или work работала так скажем в фоновом режиме. Тоесть должна запустится work(начинается смена значений) и выводится сообщение "Enter  to check current status: ", затем когда пользователь введёт check на экран должно вывестись текущее значение счётчика(напоминаю оно меняется ежесекундно), надеюсь вы поняли. Слышал это можно сделать как-то с помощью threading но у меня не получилось. Вот код (с разными попытками):

```
from time import sleep
from time import time
import threading

class Counter():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_min(self):
        self.min = int(input("Enter min - "))

    def set_max(self):
        self.max = int(input("Enter max - "))

    def print_min_max(self):
        print("Min =", self.min, "Max =", self.max)

    def work(self):

        for self.current in range(self.min, self.max + 1):
            sleep(1 - time()%1)
            #x = threading.Thread(target = self.check_current())
            #x.start()
            #self.check_current()

        #request = str(input("Enter <check> to check current status: "))
        #if request == "check":
        #print("Current status:", self.current)

        self.current = self.min
        print("Counter reset to min value")

    def check_current(self):
        #x = threading.Thread(target = self.work())
        #x.start()
        request = str(input("Enter <check> to check current status: "))
        if request == "check":
            print("Current status:", self.current)
            #break



Clock = Counter("Clock")
Clock.set_min()
Clock.set_max()
Clock.print_min_max()

#Clock.check_current()
#Clock.work()
```

Comment: Что вам конкретно надо?

Comment: @ІванШнір В смысле? Я же конкретно описал, что нужно, подробнее уже некуда, запускается work и пока цикл работает мне нужно в какой-то момент получить его текущее значение.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте так, сначало импортируйте модуль sys и место етого `request = str(input("Enter <check> to check current status: "))` напишите ето `sys.stdout.write("Enter <check> to check current status: ") request = str(sys.stdin.read())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from time import sleep
from time import time
import threading

class Counter():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_min(self):
        self.min = int(input("Enter min - "))

    def set_max(self):
        self.max = int(input("Enter max - "))

    def print_min_max(self):
        print("Min =", self.min, "Max =", self.max)

    def work(self):

        for self.current in range(self.min, self.max + 1):
            sleep(1 - time()%1) # это равно одной секунде?

        self.current = self.min
        print("Counter reset to min value")

    def check_current(self):
        while True:
            request = str(input("Enter <check> to check current status: "))
            if request == "check":
                print("Current status:", self.current)
            if request == "break":
                break



Clock = Counter("Clock")
Clock.set_min()
Clock.set_max()
Clock.print_min_max()

t = threading.Thread(target=Clock.work)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

Clock.check_current()
```

суть заключается в следующем, мы запускаем в отдельном потоке функцию которая считает. А в основном потоке включаем бесконечный цикл ожидающий событие от пользователя. Добавляем также команду, так как нам нужно дать пользователю возможность завершить программу. Важный момент, когда счетчик достигнет max. значение поменяется на min и поток по факту будет завершен.

а теперь о том как бы сделал я. задача простая. нам также нужно 2 метода. и список. так как список это изменяемый тип данных то мы можем получать таким образом информацию из потока

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import threading

stat = [0]


def work(min, max):
    while True:
        for current in range(min, max):
            stat[0] = current
            time.sleep(1) # вот это равно одной секунде


def main():
    min = int(input("Min:"))
    max = int(input("Max:"))
    t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(min, max))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    while True:
        request = str(input("Enter <check> to check current status: "))
        if request == "check":
            print("Current status:", stat[0])
        if request == "break":
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

при этом когда счетчик достигнет max, он начнет сначала. сами решите какое поведение вам приемлемо

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за оба варианта, всё понял, теперь буду знать, согласен, что 2 вариант будет по лучше)))